# Ajax in Joomla for a self developed module

Tags: jquery, ajax, joomla

I´m trying to use **[com_ajax](https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface)** for a module I´m creating.

But in my browser console, I get the following error:

**"Method getAjax does not exist."**

According to the **[com_ajax](https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface)** All methods must end in `Ajax`

therefore my code below in the jQuery request, the url `&method=get` should refer to the function called `getAjax()` in my helper file

My jQuery request looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.trash').click(function(){
        var del_id= jQuery(this).attr('id');
        var $ele = jQuery(this).parent();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'index.php?option=com_ajax&module=usernotes&method=getFilterData&format=json',
            data:{del_id:del_id},
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                /*if(data=="YES"){
                    $ele.fadeOut().remove();
                }else{
                    alert("Fejl: kan ikke slettes")
                }*/
            }
        })
    })
});
```

and this is what I got in my helper file:

```
class modUserNoteHelper
{
    public static function getFilterDataAjax() {
        $output = $_POST['del_id'];
        echo $output;
        return $output;
    }
}
```

I´ve also tried like this, which gives me a **POST 404** error in the console

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.trash').click(function(){
        var del_id= jQuery(this).attr('id');
        request = {
            'option' : 'com_ajax',
            'module' : 'usernotes',
            'method' : 'getFilterData',
            'data'   :  del_id,
            'format' : 'raw'
        };
        jQuery.ajax({            
            data   : request,
            type   : 'post',
            success: function( response ) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work! Not sure what made it work, as I´ve tried a really lot and lot count of what did the job..

Here's the working code:
**jQuery request**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.trash').click(function(){
        var del_id= jQuery(this).attr('id');
        var toDelete = jQuery(this).parent().parent();
        console.log(del_id);
        jQuery.ajax({            
            url: "index.php?option=com_ajax&module=usernotes&format=json&Id="+del_id,
            success: function( response ) {
                console.log(response);
                if(response){
                    toDelete.slideUp("normal", function() { jQuery(this).remove(); } );
                }else{
                    alert("can't delete the row");
                }
            }
        });
    })
});
```

**my mod_usernotes.php**

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$view = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('view');
$articleId = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getInt('id');


if (!$user->guest && $view == "article") {

    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/helper.php';
    $helper = new modUserNotesHelper();
    require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_usernotes');

    if (isset($_POST))
    {
        $post = $app->input->post->get('NoteForm', array(), 'array');
        $helper->CheckUserNote($post);
    }
    $helper->GetUserNotes();

}
```

**My helper**

```
public static function getAjax()
    {
        $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        $idToDelete  = $input->get("Id"); 

        $db = JFactory::getDbo();

        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        // delete all custom keys for user 1001.
        $conditions = array(
        $db->quoteName('id') . ' = ' . $idToDelete
        );

        $query->delete($db->quoteName('#__user_notes'));
        $query->where($conditions);

        $db->setQuery($query);

        $result = $db->execute();

        return($result);
    }
```